# Refresh div with Jquery on click

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

Lets say I have a page with div and mysql data in it. For example code below:

```
<div id="example">
  <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>Name</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

      <?php $num_rows=1 ; // store the record of the "tblstudent" table into $row while ($row=m ysqli_fetch_array($result)) { // Print out the contents of the entry echo '<tr>'; echo '<td>' . $num_rows . '</td>'; echo '<td>' . $row[ 'name'] . '</td>'; $num_rows++;
      } ?>

    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

If I want to only refresh certain part of my page in this case the `<div id="example">`, How can I do that with just a single page and not using `.load()` or  `$.post`. Is it actually possible??

Comment: what is your use case and why are you against using ajax?

Comment: @charlietfl , he wants to explore , rather than doing same other people tried using ajax

Answer (score 1):

What you posted is PHP - within PHP there's no way to update the page at all. You'd be using JavaScript do that.

If you want to refresh a certain part of your page, AJAX is typically the way to do it (either `$.ajax` or `.load()`). Since you don't want/are unable to use AJAX, an IFRAME is really the only other way to do it. Frame out your content in a separate page, then include it via an IFRAME. You can use one of these two methods to refresh it:

```
document.getElementById('#FRAME').contentDocument.location.reload(true);

var iframe = document.getElementById(FrameId);
iframe.src = iframe.src;
```

Answer (score 1):

what you do clone your object on page load. You need to take global variable.

```
var cloneObj;
$(document).ready(function (){
    cloneObj= $("#example1").clone();
});
```

Now whenever you need to refresh that element just call this block of code given below.

```
$("#example1").replaceWith(cloneObj.clone());
```

I have used this code in my previous answer. please check this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sarawagiakash/qytdu1zs/6/)

I hope it helps you. If not than please ask. I will try again

Comment: didn't work on refresh. It's not important really because I got it done using `load()` only that I'm curious whether there's  other alternative for loading external file or echo json.